# Which fonts in images when using URW Palladio, Palatino, etc

Tags: fonts, typography, sans-serif

I am using the **URW Palladio L** font in my LaTeX document. For the section headings, as well as the main text. I have many **images** which include texts. This text is in the sizes between **8pt** and **12pt**, so relatively small.

So far I have used **Calibri** for the font in my images (as I create them with MS Visio). It looks fine, but are there better fonts, which match with the URW Palladio L font?

Apparently, URW Paladio, TeX Gyre Pagella or Palantino, it is more or less the same. These are serif fonts, Calibiri is a sans serif.

What do you think would be a good font choice?

Comment: If the PDF will be printed to paper (rather than Ebook or other digital document), be aware that images may be rasterized to lower resolution that you expected. Depends on the printer, so there is no universal rule. As you noted, sans-serif is best, since there is less fine detail to lose. A font that has its thin stems at about the same size as its thick stems, will often look best. This is less important for digital documents, with vector text written next to or overlaying the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Futura is the traditional choice of sans font for Palatino.  But this is very much a matter of personal taste.  There are some ideas in this [graphic designer's blog](http://morganelye.com/articles/10-typeface-pairs-for-cash-poor-designers) that might help.

To get the Palatino+Futura combination on my Mac with `xelatex` I have this in my pre-amble

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont{Futura}
```

Comment: @RevMoon You're welcome.  And if you do not get any more useful answers, perhaps you could accept the answer to clear it off the unanswered list.

Comment: Most definitely, sooner or later :)

Answer (score 2):

There is Palatino Sans, available from Linotype. Unfortunately, it is a paid font. Also, it does not have math support. Link: https://www.linotype.com/3201/palatino-sans.html

[image: palatino sans linotype]

(Image taken from the link above)

Answer (score 1):

Try Linux Biolinum, Gill Sans, Tex Gyre Heros (Helvetica), Iwona, Vera (Bera) or something completely different. You can also stay with Calibri, it is really well designed typeface, you could choose much worse:) As Thruston said: "this is very much a matter of personal taste".